# Is this enough to say that two lines are parallel?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> The diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ intersect at $O$. We are given a line $p$ that passes through $O$ and intersects $AB$ and $CD$ at $M$ and $N$, respectively; a line $q$ that passes through $M$ ($q$ is parallel to $CD$) and $q$ intersects $AC$ at $E$; a line $k$ that passes through $N$ ($k$ is parallel to $AB$) and $k$ intersects $BD$ at $F$. I should show that $BE$ is parallel to $CF$.
>   [image]

I showed $\dfrac{BO}{OF}=\dfrac{EO}{CO}$. Is this enough to say $BE \parallel CF$ only by using Intercept theorem (Thales' theorem)? Must I also show that $ \dfrac{OE}{OC}=\dfrac{OB}{OF}=\dfrac{EB}{CF}$? We haven't studied similar triangles!

Comment: This is [the same problem you posted yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3522233/409). Rather than re-posting, you should simply have edited the previous version to add your additional thoughts.

Comment: Is there a problem I posted it again with my additional thoughts?

Comment: *"Is there a problem I posted it again with my additional thoughts?"* ... Well, now there are two virtually-identical questions floating around, which adds to site bloat and confusion. Deleting an older version usually isn't a good idea. Certainly, if it has been answered, then deleting is inconsiderate to the answerer(s); but even an unanswered question may have a solution "in the works", and I can attest that it's frustrating to return to the site ready to post an answer only to find the question gone. (It won't necessarily be clear to anyone that the deleted question has been replaced.)